# Babel loader crashing npm build

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs

After adding babel to my node project, my project is no longer building.

I was originally getting an issue that said:

```
ERROR in ./src/js/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module '@babel/core'
```

After looking, it seemed like the problem was that I had installed `babel-core` instead of `@babel/core`. I then installed `@babel/core` using the following command:

```
npm install @babel/core --save-dev
```

After that, the project was still crashing. The new error is

```
ERROR in ./src/js/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindings' of null
```

and I do not know how to fix it. Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/js/index.js'],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'js/bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist'
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: './src/index.html'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Please let me know what I need to change in my configuration to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a few things here:

You need to install:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-env
```

And then add a .babelrc file to your directory and fill it with the following:

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env", {
                "modules": false
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```